# How is gender variance classified in the cognitive sciences?

Tags: terminology, gender

I'm trying to do a quick, informal literature survey of current language pertaining to gender variant/trans* people.  Do any important texts still use Gender Identity Disorder, or other language that indicates some kind of impairment or "red flag"?

I'm not currently familiar enough with the literature to know what other places I should be looking--I've seen references to Kaplan and Sadock here and there, and an American Psychiatric Publishing Textbook of Psychiatry, but haven't seen the texts.  I also have absolutely no idea if there's corresponding Psychology literature.

Comment: In case it's not immediately apparent, I placed what research I've done in my answer below. Hopefully my answer existing doesn't deter others from answering, because I know my answer is incomplete.

Answer (score 4):

So far, I've found that the American Psychiatric Association's DSM 5 has made it abundantly clear they no longer consider gender variance itself a disorder, to the point of a [2012 position statement on access to care](http://www.psychiatry.org/File%20Library/Learn/Archives/Position-2012-Transgender-Gender-Variant-Access-Care.pdf), a [2012 "Position Statement on Discrimination Against Transgender and Gender Variant Individuals"](http://www.psychiatry.org/File%20Library/Learn/Archives/Position-2012-Transgender-Gender-Variant-Discrimination.pdf), and updated language in the DSM.

It also looks like ICD-11's beta now uses "Gender Incongruence", versus the various "gender identity disorders" under the F64 code in ICD-10.  Link when I have the reputation to post it.